# Colocar uma url dentro de option select

Tags: html, script

Como colocar uma url dentro do option de um select? Quando o usuário selecionar a opção do select ele já redirecionaria para url dentro do option.

Da forma que tentei a url é concatenada com a anterior e o link fica quebrado.

Comment: Você quer abrir uma nova página de acordo com a opção que o cara selecionar num select?

Comment: sim mas no meu caso aqui vão ser 3 select diferentes com varios options  chamando varias paginas indo e voltando entres eles

Comment: São paginas internas dentro do próprio sistema mesmo Ex: cada option pai muda os option do select filho e  option do filho muda as opçoes do select neto  tipo assim

Comment: Coloque um exemplo do que você ja fez para que fique mais claro a sua necessidade...

Answer (score 1):

Faça da seguinte forma:

```
<select id="link">
   <option value="" selected>Escolha o site</option>
   <option value="http://www.google.com">Google</option>
   <option value="http://www.youtube.com">YouTube</option>
   <option value="http://pt.stackoverflow.com/">Stack</option>
</select>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){

    $('#link').on('change', function () {
         var url = $(this).val(); 
         if (url) { 
             window.open(url, '_blank');
          }
          return false;
        });
     });
</script>
```

Comment: Considere adicionar uma alternativa com javascript. O user não mencionou a utilização de `jQuery`

Answer (score 1):

Método simples:

```
<select onchange="location.href=this.value">
 <option value="#">Selecione</option>
 <option value="http://www.botafogo.com.br">Botafogo</option>
 <option value="http://www.flamengo.com.br">Flamengo</option>
 <option value="http://www.fluminense.com.br">Fluminense</option>
 <option value="http://www.vasco.com.br">Vasco da Gama</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para colocar o link dentro de um único option faça como a seguir:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeFunc($i) {
    if ($i == 'nova'){
        window.open('index.php?pg=cadastrar_categoria','_self');
    }
}
</script>

<select id="link"  onchange="changeFunc(value);">
   <option value="" >Escolha a categoria</option>
   <option value="animais">Animais</option>
   <option value="natureza">Natureza</option>
   <option value="nova">Adicionar nova categoria</option>
</select>
```